# stacking time series data on top of each other (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some time-series data where I have filtered it down to a subset of the time series (i.e. the month of March).

I would like to apply similar methods as the `ggseasonalplot` and `ggsubseriesplot` from the `forecast` package: https://rdrr.io/cran/forecast/man/seasonplot.html

I would like to plot line plots for the section of time-series data that I have.

For example using stock data (for simplicity) where I convert the returns to monthly returns I can use the following:

```
library(tidyqaunt)
library(timetk)
dd <- tq_get("IBM",
             from = "2010-01-01",
             to = "2015-01-01") %>% 
  tq_transmute(select = close, mutate_fun = periodReturn,
            period = "monthly", type = "log") %>% 
  tk_ts(start = c(2010, 1), frequency = 12)

ggseasonplot(dd, color = "darkred")
ggsubseriesplot(dd)
```

I would like a similar plot but for the just the period of days I have in March - usng my data below -.

```
> d %>% 
+   group_by(year(date)) %>% 
+   summarise(n())
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  `year(date)` `n()`
         <int> <int>
1         2011    31
2         2012    31
3         2013    31
4         2014    31
5         2015    31
6         2016    31
7         2017    31
8         2018    31
9         2019    31
```

Expected output is a `ggplot` plot with different lines for the periods that I have similar to `ggseasonplot` from the `forecast` package. It would be nice to also get the daily plot for the `ggsubseriesplot` also, using `ggsubseriesplot(dd)`.

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(year = c(2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), month = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3), date = structure(c(15034, 15035, 15036, 15037, 
15038, 15039, 15040, 15041, 15042, 15043, 15044, 15045, 15046, 
15047, 15048, 15049, 15050, 15051, 15052, 15053, 15054, 15055, 
15056, 15057, 15058, 15059, 15060, 15061, 15062, 15063, 15064, 
15400, 15401, 15402, 15403, 15404, 15405, 15406, 15407, 15408, 
15409, 15410, 15411, 15412, 15413, 15414, 15415, 15416, 15417, 
15418, 15419, 15420, 15421, 15422, 15423, 15424, 15425, 15426, 
15427, 15428, 15429, 15430, 15765, 15766, 15767, 15768, 15769, 
15770, 15771, 15772, 15773, 15774, 15775, 15776, 15777, 15778, 
15779, 15780, 15781, 15782, 15783, 15784, 15785, 15786, 15787, 
15788, 15789, 15790, 15791, 15792, 15793, 15794, 15795, 16130, 
16131, 16132, 16133, 16134, 16135, 16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 
16140, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145, 16146, 16147, 16148, 
16149, 16150, 16151, 16152, 16153, 16154, 16155, 16156, 16157, 
16158, 16159, 16160, 16495, 16496, 16497, 16498, 16499, 16500, 
16501, 16502, 16503, 16504, 16505, 16506, 16507, 16508, 16509, 
16510, 16511, 16512, 16513, 16514, 16515, 16516, 16517, 16518, 
16519, 16520, 16521, 16522, 16523, 16524, 16525, 16861, 16862, 
16863, 16864, 16865, 16866, 16867, 16868, 16869, 16870, 16871, 
16872, 16873, 16874, 16875, 16876, 16877, 16878, 16879, 16880, 
16881, 16882, 16883, 16884, 16885, 16886, 16887, 16888, 16889, 
16890, 16891, 17226, 17227, 17228, 17229, 17230, 17231, 17232, 
17233, 17234, 17235, 17236, 17237, 17238, 17239, 17240, 17241, 
17242, 17243, 17244, 17245, 17246, 17247, 17248, 17249, 17250, 
17251, 17252, 17253, 17254, 17255, 17256, 17591, 17592, 17593, 
17594, 17595, 17596, 17597, 17598, 17599, 17600, 17601, 17602, 
17603, 17604, 17605, 17606, 17607, 17608, 17609, 17610, 17611, 
17612, 17613, 17614, 17615, 17616, 17617, 17618, 17619, 17620, 
17621, 17956, 17957, 17958, 17959, 17960, 17961, 17962, 17963, 
17964, 17965, 17966, 17967, 17968, 17969, 17970, 17971, 17972, 
17973, 17974, 17975, 17976, 17977, 17978, 17979, 17980, 17981, 
17982, 17983, 17984, 17985, 17986), class = "Date"), y_var = c(22, 
35, 43, 52, 38, 43, 38, 40, 40, 48, 60, 28, 24, 38, 29, 32, 37, 
61, 36, 35, 32, 22, 34, 42, 49, 31, 17, 29, 28, 26, 65, 53, 55, 
28, 24, 22, 33, 42, 59, 42, 36, 34, 50, 59, 64, 52, 32, 19, 12, 
11, 22, 39, 59, 48, 41, 36, 37, 40, 33, 30, 42, 49, 30, 38, 20, 
25, 44, 39, 25, 34, 18, 10, 14, 19, 15, 21, 42, 26, 42, 15, 47, 
NA, 47, 43, 26, 13, 13, 14, 14, 8, 8, 10, 19, 13, 9, 12, 13, 
27, 49, 51, 46, 27, 42, 40, 36, 40, 57, 36, 36, 53, 54, 39, 50, 
33, 10, 18, 37, 13, 17, 48, 30, 24, 22, 46, 18, 34, 52, 41, 32, 
61, 67, 44, 63, 66, 79, 76, 47, 22, 19, 54, 42, 36, 21, 31, 22, 
19, 40, 29, 22, 36, 30, 44, 30, 48, 56, 89, 56, 45, 33, 17, 17, 
20, 30, 45, 19, 22, 38, 27, 35, 45, 77, 52, 37, 24, 21, 27, 26, 
36, 38, 49, 31, 10, 18, 21, 48, 16, 40, 62, 49, 17, 17, 23, 31, 
77, 67, 61, 45, 17, 11, 19, 25, 31, 42, 58, 41, 23, 26, 23, 35, 
34, 39, 22, 23, 42, 55, 50, 31, 27, 42, 19, 18, 24, 23, 27, 44, 
44, 25, 7, 15, 26, 35, 14, 22, 19, 12, 20, 16, 14, 51, 51, 7, 
10, 33, 26, 28, 8, 5, 8, 34, 47, 24, 6, 18, 9, 11, 26, 36, 32, 
26, 24, 9, 25, 47, 27, 7, 10, 14, 18, 40, 40, 31, 23, 21, 13, 
38, 45, 36, 24, 18)), row.names = c(NA, -279L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to plot your data depending on taste. One way is to group by the year and then just plot the lines in difference colors, similar to the `ggseasonplot`. Another option is to facet on the years, and there are multiple ways to do this. The final choice depends on taste but also depends on the data.

```
library(lubridate)  # For date-related functions
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

**Option 1**: Group by year

```
d %>%
  mutate(Day=day(date), year=factor(year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=y_var, col=year, group=year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,7)) +
  ggtitle("Monthly plot: March") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 8)
```

---

[image]

Maybe not so good since there is little change over the years (spaghetti plot).

---

**Option 2**: Facet by year (multiple rows and columns).

```
d %>%
  mutate(Day=day(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=y_var)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,7)) +
  ggtitle("Monthly plot: March") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---

**Option 3**: Facet by year (many rows, 1 column)

```
d %>%
  mutate(Day=day(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=y_var)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~year, ncol=1, strip.position = "right") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,7)) +
  ggtitle("Monthly plot: March") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---

**Option 4**: Facet grid (1 row, many columns)

```
d %>%
  mutate(Day=day(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=y_var)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~year) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,7)) +
  ggtitle("Monthly plot: March") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

---